# Python syntax error when defining the element end for printing a table

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a single row, but this line of code is always causing me a syntax error.
Here's my code:

```
for a in range(0,3):
    for x in range(0,3):
        index = random.randrange(0,len(word_List))

print("     ", word_List[index], end= ' ',) # prints in a single row 
first_Grid.append(word_List.pop(index))
```

Comment: Can you please show the syntax error? Also, what is `word_list`?

Comment: This line :print ("     ", word_List[index], end= ' ',) # prints in a single row --- in particular the equals sign

Comment: word_List = [] , to hold words from an external file

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP edited yesterday's question into a completely different one today.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was changed from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
print("     {}".format(word_List[index]), end= ' ')
```

Also note that if you're using Python 2.x instead of 3.x, you either need to add:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

To the top of your file, or use this instead:

```
print "     {}".format(word_List[index]), end=" "
```